# How do I resolve GLIBC error during compilation?

Tags: linux, cmake, makefile, glibc, rhel

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 with ldd version = ldd (GNU libc) 2.17, when I try to build my code using makefile the following error is seen :

```
//usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_get@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__h_errno@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libpci.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
//usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_get_override@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__sendmmsg@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_get_preinit@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
//usr/lib64/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__resolv_context_put@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I resolve this issue?

The current ldd version is 2.17, should I try to upgrade GLIBC? This is a freshly installed server, Am i missing any configurations?

Comment: The initial `\\` on paths seems to point to errors on your building tools. I would also check your building instructions (so the building and compiling, not the link stage)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi could you provide me your email so that i can send you the build log , i am not able to pin point the error in the build log

Comment: No. It is not an easy task, so I would not do it (but when I must do it, so for my projects). Did you clean the source code? No binaries left (there may be old object files or old libraries files referenced in it). Did you followed the insturction on how to configure? Check configuration step, and this time at every single warning and error (usually we skip it, but if you have an error.. check). Also when compiling: check the first warning and error.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ldd` (what you quoted) and `ld` (what you invoked) are completely different programs.

You should show the actual command you invoked, in your question.  My suspicion is that you are invoking `ld` directly.  This is generally not a good idea unless you have very specific (and relatively unusual) needs.  Usually you would use the compiler front-end (e.g., `gcc` or whatever) to link your program; it will call `ld` itself after adding all the relevant libraries.

However if you're using the resolver you might need to add `-lresolv` to your link line.